# Filtering from changing set in dplyr / data.table instead of for loop

Tags: r, filter, data.table, dplyr

I've got a `data.frame` with 2 columns: Time of the user request in seconds (ranges from `1` to `86400`) and the user ID. After counting number of requests, unique requests and IDs of unique request for every second I'm setting the time window - say 10 seconds. Now for every second I want to find a list of new  unique IDs that appeared in this specific second and didn't appeared in my time interval [x-1, x-window] (where x means specific second), count number of this IDs and number of unique IDs in time interval.

I accomplished this using `for` loop but it's really slow. Is there a way to get the same effect using `data.table` or `dplyr` package (or some other faster technique) ?

Simple data:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
data<- structure(list(Second = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                              2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), UniqueId = c(1L, 
                                                                                                    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 
                                                                                                    12L, 13L, 1L, 11L, 9L, 14L, 15L)), .Names = c("Second", "UniqueId"
                                                                                                    ), row.names = c(NA, -23L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                    ))

>head(data)
   # A tibble: 6 × 2
  Second UniqueId
   <int>    <int>
1      1        1
2      1        1
3      1        2
4      1        3
5      1        4
6      1        5


# Statistics per second
data2<- data %>% group_by(Second) %>%
     summarise(n_req=n(),n_uniq_req=n_distinct(UniqueId),
            Ids=list(unique(UniqueId))) %>%
 arrange(Second) %>%
 ungroup() 

window <- 2 # two second window

data3<-data2 %>% mutate(New_Ids=NA, UniqueUsersInMemory=NA,
                    NewRequest=NA)

New_Ids=list()
UniqueUsersInMemory=c()
NewRequest=c()
for(i in 1:nrow(data2)){
  temp<- unlist(data2[(data2$Second<data2$Second[i] &   data2$Second>=data2$Second[i]-window),"Ids"])
  New_Ids[[i]]<-setdiff(unlist(data2[i,"Ids"]),temp)
  UniqueUsersInMemory[[i]]<-length(unique(temp))
  NewRequest[[i]]<-length(unique(New_Ids[[i]]))
}
data3$New_Ids<-New_Ids
data3$UniqueUsersInMemory<-UniqueUsersInMemory
data3$NewRequest<-NewRequest
```

In the end I'm getting something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a non-equi join, you can define many summary statistics:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(data)
setnames(DT, c("s", "id"))
setcolorder(DT, c("id","s"))
setorder(DT)

window = 2
DT[.(id = id, s0 = s - window, s1 = s), on=.(id, s >= s0, s < s1), 
  .(is_new = .N == 0)
, by=.EACHI][, -2][, .(
  n_r     = .N,
  n_newr  = sum(is_new),
  n_id    = uniqueN(id),
  ids     = toString(unique(id)),
  n_newid = uniqueN(id[is_new]),
  newids  = toString(unique(id[is_new]))
), keyby=s]

   s n_r n_newr n_id           ids n_newid        newids
1: 1   6      6    5 1, 2, 3, 4, 5       5 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2: 2   5      3    5 2, 3, 6, 7, 8       3       6, 7, 8
3: 3   4      2    4   3, 7, 9, 10       2         9, 10
4: 4   4      4    4 1, 11, 12, 13       4 1, 11, 12, 13
5: 5   4      2    4 9, 11, 14, 15       2        14, 15
```

The `-2` drops the second column (called `s0` in the `on=`); and the `keyby` sorts the result by `s`.

Comment: I may not have captured all of the OP's desired columns, but tbh, they should ask one question at a time, not ten (as done here).

Comment: You switched names in `setnames` and `setcolorder`. Thank you for help, now I have to add count for unique ID's in time interval and it'll be done. Sorry for confusion and a lot of questions, I was mostly interested in changing the `for` loop.

Comment: @Maju116 Ah, good catch. Fixed. I was wondering why my results looked nothing like yours. I think `n_id = uniqueN(id)` sounds like "unique IDs in time interval", but I may be misunderstanding. If you can't figure it out, you could consider posting a new question of course.

Comment: `n_id` is number of unique IDs in this specified second, unique IDs in time interval are unique IDs in two seconds before this specified second (`UniqueUsersInMemory` in my code). Of course, if I won't figure it out I'll think about another question. Thanks once more :)

Comment: Swich names in `setcolorder` too. :)

Comment: @Maju116 Hm, do I need to switch it there, too? I just prefer the layout with ID before time, is all. I don't expect it to affect the results...? For unique IDs in the time interval, maybe join `on=` with time but without id.

Comment: The results are different, so I think yes.

Comment: @Maju Ok, the results are substantively the same, just the sort order differs, I think. I changed it to `keyby=s` so it's sorted that way.